# Nothing happen after pressing facebook login button

Tags: android, facebook

```
package com.example.tabv3;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FacebookFragment extends Fragment {

    public static CallbackManager callbackmanager;
    LoginButton lb; 

            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("FacebookFragment","Called");
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("FacebookFragment","onCreateview Called");

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.facebook_layout, container, false);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
        callbackmanager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        lb=(LoginButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        lb.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "email", "user_friends");

        lb.registerCallback(callbackmanager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
                Log.i("TAG", "Facebook login successful.");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logged in successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String token=result.getAccessToken().getToken();
                Log.i("TokenSuccess",token);
                GraphRequest request=GraphRequest.newMeRequest(result.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback(){

                        @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("Login ACtivity",response.toString());
                    try
                    {
                        String name=object.getString("name");
                        String email=object.getString("email");
                        String gender=object.getString("gender");
                        String birthday=object.getString("birthday");
                        Log.i("Name"+name,"Gender"+gender+birthday);
                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                    }); 
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields","name,gender,birthday,email");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }//onSuccess End

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Logging in canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("TAG", "Facebook login canceled.");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error occurred while logging in. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("TAG", "Facebook login error.");
                        Log.e("FAcebbok", "Error", error);
                    }
                });




        return rootView;

         }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i("onactivityResult","CALLED");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackmanager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

ater running this code facebook login button appears and then when I press it show me a spinner for one second and nothing happened.

Here I am using `Fragment` I don't want to use `FragmentActivity`

Please suggest me where am lacking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was lacking a point which i solved

actually i was implementing `onActivityResult` function in the `Fragment` class instead of the `Activity` Class in which i am adding the `Fragment` this small issue solved my problem probably helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

Probably you dont have an context at your class. Make sure you have the current activity when you call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize method.

FacebookFragment should have an instance of Activity wich you use like
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(currentActivity.getApplicationContext())

:D

Comment: Your answer looks helpful, but your first sentence makes it look unhelpful. Deleting that might prevent others from scrolling on by.

Comment: it needs app's context and not Activity's context

Answer (score 0):

If you activity doesn't implement onActivityResult you can't handle with facebook result and your registered callback from facebook login Button will be useless.

Comment: what is the significance of your answer,whereas i already put what is the fault

Answer (score 0):

if your onActivityResult inside a fragment, use this:

```
loginButton.setFragment(this);
```